# Destructure a List of Pairs

Tags: raku, rakudo

Consider

```
.say for (1,2,2).rotor(2=>-1).map( -> ($a, $b) { $a - $b })
```

which works as expected. However,

```
.say for (1,2,2).pairs.rotor(2=>-1).map( -> ($a, $b) { $a.value - $b.value })
```

throws

```
Too few positionals passed to '<anon>'; expected 2 arguments but got 0 in sub-signature
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

> This is Rakudo Star version 2019.03.1 built on MoarVM version 2019.03
>   implementing Perl 6.d.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is taking the `Pair` as a `Capture`, thus turning the `Pair` into a named argument:

```
$ raku -e '(a => 42, b => 666).map: -> |c { dd c }'
\(:a(42))
\(:b(666))
```

In your example, it then doesn't pass any positional arguments, thus causing the observed execution error.

jnthn++ for pointing this out.

Comment: Coercion to a `Capture` is precisely how destructuring works.

Answer (score 0):

btw - I was wondering why |c and not \c ... from the doc...

> Inside a Signature, a Capture may be created by prefixing a sigilless
>   parameter with a vertical bar |. This packs the remainder of the
>   argument list into that parameter.